# Test for equal mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a control experiment and an experiment. In these two experiments, I can detect different peptides. The presence of the peptides in the experiment is measured by determining the concentration of the peptide. At the end, I have a table like this:

```
Peptide    Control       Experiment
A          C1, C2, C3    E1, E2, E3, E4
```

with hundreds of peptides and different concentration values in the control and the experiment dependeing on wehther the peptide X was detected in the replicates of the control and the experiment.

If I want to identify peptides with different concentration in the control and the experiment I could do an ANOVA test and then peptides for which `p < a` are the ones I am looking for. Also for lower `a` levels I get fewer peptides.

My problem is that I am after the peptides that behave the same in the control and the experiment. If I do an ANOVA test and then I take the peptides for which `p > a`, then I get that for smaller `a` levels I get more peptide, which makes no sense to me.

So I guess I need a test that invert the null and alternative hypothesis of ANOVA. Is this guess correct? Is there any test with `H0: μC ≠ μE` and `H1: μC = μE?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is equivalence test.

See for example:

```
doi:10.1021/ac053390m
doi:10.1016/j.foodqual.2012.05.003
doi:10.1177/1948550617697177
doi:10.1037/a0029146
```